# How can I use aliases in a module / plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm writing a module that needs to grab the path of a file.

I know I can use `{{ alias('@webroot') }}` in the templates to get the root web folder. Is there a way I can do this in module/plugin land?

I've been looking for PHP constants or similar, and landed on `$fullpath = CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/web/' . $filename;` which doesn't feel great.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would it be an option for you to use

```
Craft::getAlias('@webroot');
```

[Yii2 Aliases](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-aliases#resolving-aliases)